# Opal.rb bridged class inner mechanics

Tags: opalrb

I want to know how exactly bridging to native classes does internally work. (can't find any documentation on that).

`function NativeClass() { this.foo = "bar"; }`


`class MyClass <`NativeClass`; end`

Is it similar to ES6's or coffeescript's inheritance (from JS perspective)?

Is it possible to define methods on function that can be called like regular ones (like:

`RubyClass``.prototype`.foo = function(){return RubyClass instances' @accessor}`) not the`.$foo`.

And one more thing.
If Ruby class is inheriting from native class,
is it possible to reference in that function to the instance of Foo class that'll be instantiated, like `function(){this.bar = Foo's instance}?`

Is it possible to return native class from Ruby class (that inherited from native) (for example if some JS library needs native class as arg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically any Opal class is a full blown object instance of the class Class with some additional properties. The most relevant in this context are `$$proto` which holds the class' prototype and `$$alloc` which holds the original class constructor.

Mapping the C-Ruby implementation `#allocate` will call `$$alloc` internally and `Class#new` will call in sequence `#allocate` and `#initialize` (just like regular Ruby).

As of bridged classes are made building a full blown `Class` instance and injecting in the prototype and constructor of the native JS class. Then methods from `BasicObject` are copied over and (IIRC) `Kernel` is mixed in.

For further details I suggest reading the relevant parts directly from the Opal source. When I did it I learned a lot! :)

Some starting points are:

- [runtime.js](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/fc70e863601515009f458f42d6704adff9981be7/opal/corelib/runtime.js#L136) in which the passed superclass is checked for being a function
- [class.rb](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/fc70e863601515009f458f42d6704adff9981be7/opal/corelib/class.rb#L4-L38) the `.new` and `#allocate` methods from `Class`